Accute sign does not work as first character of a line
I have a problem when i type ´ + E or ´ + A, it should produces É and Á but it is deleted instantaneously.
In firefox search bar it works as expect, but in skype or whatsapp it doesnt.
My keybord is abnt2. I'm using Archlinux and Firefox 132.0.2 (64-bits) how to I provide info for the plugins I have?
